# Calming down feral cat to take to vet?

Tags: cats, safety, feral, animal-handling

There's a feral cat in our house that's always fighting with other feral cats. He's a really nice cat, but he's a big adult street cat and I know he won't let me pick him up.

What can I give this cat so he gets sleepy (or even falls asleep) and I can pick him up and put him in a cage? I would like to neuter him, because I really like him. But I can't have him peeing/marking everything and getting in fights with other cats.

I don't want to buy an automatic cage that closes when they walk into the cage.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried putting catnip in a cage? Depending on the cat, he maybe able to let you pick him up after they’ve had their catnip experience.

Answer (score 4):

Your local animal shelter can probably lend you a suitable trap and advise you on where to place it, how to bait it, and how to use it safely. They will likely be thrilled to help you since you're helping with the feral cat population.

> I don't want to buy an automatic cage that closes when they walk into the cage.

If your concern is the cost of the cage, borrowing one from a shelter should be free. If your concern is that the cat might get injured, the design of these cages is very safe. By following the shelter's advice, you should be fine. And if your concern is that the cat might hold a grudge against you, that's unlikely. The cat will be wary of the cage, but should have no reason to associate the experience with you.

Comment: I think this is a safe way (for both cat and human) to approach it and sensible advice. There is a risk that any medication intended for the big cat may be eaten by another animal also.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The issue is that they never get into the cage, and it's  been something I've tried many, many times. I've bought two cages, and he hasn't gone in once.

Comment: I would only use the medicine when I'm there. I would never leave the medicine unattended.

Answer (score 2):

I have had this exact problem. I have one domesticated cat and got a new cat that was a feral cat; I got him fixed but this did not help, he still chased and hurt my other cat. I did feed them in two different places to try to avoid the fighting.

This went so far as to my original cat losing a lot of weight, while the feral one had gained a lot of weight; he was about 8 years old when I got him. He was the nicest cat toward me but a nightmare to the other cat. I had been trying to do everything to make it work for over a year.

To trap your cat, take a cardboard box, tape it closed and cut a hole in one end of the box, and put some food (tuna) inside, then wait until your cat enters; this might take some time and several tries.

Once the cat is inside, tilt the box so that its opening hole faces upwards and cover the hole with a book or something larger than the hole so he doesn't escape. Place your carrier cage against the wall so it can't move and is positioned in a way that its opened door faces outwards, place the cardboard box against the carrier, then remove the book so the cat can enter the carrier cage, when the cat enters, use the book to cover the opening of the cage while you close it; this will, probably, possibly work.

My feral cat was not able to adjust so I had to take him down. I am saying this so you know what you might have to do if it doesn't work out for you and the cats.

Comment: When you say “take him down” did you mean take him to a shelter?

Comment: shelter was not an option,this was a 10+years old feral cat that was born and lived in the wild until i got him.i gave this cat the best year of his life but in the end he could not adapt to my other cat,i had to put him down to save the life of my other cat,and yes it hurts to put a healthy cat down and i will miss him just as i miss all the cats i have had in my life.

Comment: Was releasing him back into the open not an option? From what I’ve experienced feral cats thrive in the wild and eventually find their end on their own terms. There is no reason our intervention should cost a sentient being their life, even if they are close to the end of their lifespan. Nothing gives us the right to meddle and willingly terminate a life.