# acepromazine for feral cat?

Tags: cats, dogs

As I had posted in a previous question, there's a feral cat around my house that I want to neuter. He's extremely friendly (I feed him) and I can pick him up and pet him, but he just won't get into the cage. And being a *street* cat, I assume he'll defend himself if I force him into the cage. I tried once and I knew that it wouldn't work.

So I'm thinking of using acepromazine so he calms down and gets sleepy. My question: does this medication calm the cat down or does he fall asleep?

Thanks.

Comment: Putting a cat in carrier is difficult regardless of if he lives on the street or in your house.  See [Putting a cat into a carrier](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/251/putting-a-cat-into-a-carrier) for some ideas that might make drugs not needed. But please clarify where you might get acepromazine, it requires a prescription in many countries, obtaining it and dosing without a prescription may pose significant risk then to the cat

Comment: See also [Calming down feral cat to take to vet?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/17018)

Comment: Be patient and entice him with treats :) avoid drugs, who knows if he has allergies or something

Answer (score 1):

Try to use a slightly bigger carrier so you can put him in it easier. There should be no need to drug the cat.

Answer (score 0):

If you are feeding him, and he regularly comes to food try a cat trap. Most local feed stores carry these and an employee or YouTube video can teach you how to use it. You place the food inside and it closes behind them. Most of them come with a handle on top and you could carry him to the vet inside the trap. Once he's been sedated by a vet he can then be transferred into a crate or carrier.

I would fear drugging him with this tranquilizer yourself could lead to him running off and curling up for a long nap somewhere else, possibly in harm's way ESPECIALLY if it kicks in too strong and he passes out somewhere. Cats can have different reactions given acepromazine, and should be administered or prescribed a certain mlg based on weight and health by a vet.

If you don't want to trap him yourself call around some local rescues, explain your situation and they may trap, fix and release for you!